# Jenkins declarative pipeline create custom workspace for parallel builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm building a project with declarative pipelines, I want to create two different workspaces with two different names for the parallel step. How do I do it?

i.e, something like this

```
build1 workspace : /some/path/build-1
build2 workspace : /some/path/build-2
```

Comment: Is the use case to run the same job multiple times on the same build agent?

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Parallel Stages') {
            parallel {
                stage('Parallel Stage 1') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'label'
                            customWorkspace '/tmp/dir1'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo pwd()
                    }
                }
                stage('Parallel Stage 2') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'label'
                            customWorkspace '/tmp/dir2'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo pwd()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```